# MVC Ajax function call twice

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller

I have a problem with an ajax function. I want to send param to method on controller and this ajax function call method twice.

**ajax:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    $(document).on('click', '.exp', function (e) {

        var st_date = $(this).parent().find('.start').val();
        var ed_date = $(this).parent().find('.end').val();

        $.ajax({


            url: '/Reports/Report_CLeav/',

            data: {
                start_date:st_date,
                end_date:ed_date
                }
        }).success(function (data) {



           })

    });

})
```

Comment: Try to detach a handler first, like `$(document).off('click').on('click'`

Comment: Can you show us the element with `.exp`?

Comment: Html.ActionLink("Export Report", "Report_CLeav", "Reports", new { class = "IndexButton exp", @style = "text-decoration: none;color:white" })

Answer (score 0):

$(".exp").click(function() {

```
        var st_date = $(this).parent().find('.start').val();
        var ed_date = $(this).parent().find('.end').val();

        $.ajax({


            url: '/Reports/Report_CLeav/',

            data: {
                start_date:st_date,
                end_date:ed_date
                }
        }).success(function (data) {






        })

  });
```

?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <th>
                    Start date: @Html.TextBox("start_date", null, new { @class = "dateClass start", id = "StartDate" })
                    End date: @Html.TextBox("end_date", null, new { @class = "dateClass end", id = "EndDate", @data_toggle = "popover", @data_content = "End date should be greater than Start date. ", @title = "Attention" }) 

                    @Html.ActionLink("Export Report", "Report_CLeav", "Reports", new { @class = "IndexButton exp", @style = "text-decoration: none;color:white" })
                </th>
```

"Controller"
 public class ReportsController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Export
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

public void Report_CLeav(DateTime ?start_date, DateTime ? end_date)
        {
            string path = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/reports/Report_LeavingCompanyHCT.xlsx");
            Models.Report.Report_CompLeav reportcompleav = new Models.Report.Report_CompLeav();
            var fileinfo = new FileInfo(path);

```
        using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(fileinfo))
        {

            var currentWorksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets["HC"];

            using (var excelToExport = new ExcelPackage())
            {
                excelToExport.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(currentWorksheet.Name, currentWorksheet);
                var workBook = excelToExport.Workbook.Worksheets["HC"];
                try
                {
                    workBook = reportcompleav.exportAllEmployeeDataRRecords(workBook,start_date,end_date);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    ViewBag.IsError = true;
                }


                excelToExport.Save();

                Stream stream = excelToExport.Stream;
                var memoryStream = stream as MemoryStream;

                Response.Clear();
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats";
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
                                   "attachment; filename=" + fileinfo.Name);
                Response.BinaryWrite(memoryStream.ToArray());

            }
        }

    }
}
```

}